# Scratchy Violin Problem

Tags: violin

I had bought my violin last year. It is a used one, and one of the most consistent problems I am facing is the scratchy tones of the violin. I have a different one I use in my lessons, but the violin music wasn't as scratchy as the one I bought myself. I thought it may be a problem with the rosin, but it is not. I use Kaplan Premium for my violin, which is a really good rosin, but it still remained scratchy. It is not a string problem as well, as I have recently changed my E string, and the same problem remained. I tried using more or less rosin and yet, it didn't seem to get better. At this point, I practically have up. It has been a year, and it hasn't gotten better over time. Then how can I make my violin less scratchy?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, when I bought my first violin it was "really scratchy". A year later the scratch had completely disappeared! That was because the scratch had nothing to do with the violin and everything to do with the player.

As a beginner there is always a great temptation to blame the tools, the bow, the violin, the setup, the rosin, the shoulder rest (or lack of a shoulder rest if playing without). Been there, done that. But you need to learn that the first cure for any of these apparent tool-related problems is more practice.

If there really is a problem then it won't magically go away when you hand the instrument to your teacher and ask him/her to play. 999 times out of 1000 the "problem" does go away when you do that.

Comment: Correct answer. Give a beginner a Stradivari, and it'll sound just as bad as any other instrument. Give a virtuoso a “25$ plywood box” and it'll sound... _weird_, but she'll know  how to avoid it sounding bad-kind-of-scratchy regardless. Some instruments may surpress things like scratch a bit, others bring it out more notably, but ultimately the only way forward is to improve the playing technique to get rid of it entirely (or else, _deliberately use_ the scratch for musical expression).

Answer (score 0):

That's a very difficult question to answer, because there are many reasons a violin may sound scratchy.  The best thing would be if you could show it to someone who knows violins- a teacher, a good violinist, a luthier.

Answer (score 0):

First bring it to your lesson so your teacher can evaluate it.  "Scratchy" is not diagnosable over the internet :-( .   It's quite possible your strings are dead, or cheap/lousy strings to begin with.

As a warning to others,  I strongly suggest **never** buying an instrument without having your teacher or other local accomplished player evaluate it for you.  You may have bought a plywood box worth $25 US, in which case it'll never sound good, for example.

Comment: Actually, I bought both my violin and string with the advices of my teacher and a violinist I know. And my teacher already evaluated it. There was nothing wrong.

Comment: Does your "lesson violin" have the same strings?   Maybe it's simply a much better instrument than the "beginner" one you bought.   We really don't have much to go on here.

Comment: I mean, both are Cremona, both are pretty same, as I ordered my strings from the same company. The only thing that is different is the bow, as the bow in my lessons was separately bought.